# How to redirect all touch devices to a different site?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, parallax, superscrollorama

I have created a rather complex Superscrollorama animation whith a few responsive breakpoints as well, and it works smoothly on most screen sizes. However, Safari (and as such, Chrome for iOS) works a bit differently, so I had to use a script called iScroll. Even on the [mobile page for Superscrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/simpledemo_mobile.html) John mentions that this solution is quite resource-heavy and should only be used with smaller stuff. Now, my animation almost won't scroll on my iPad 4 or iPhone 5, so I guess I'm a bit over the "smaller stuff" thing. That's sad. I really wanted to be able to say that I went full responsive. :)

However, I would like to offer a decent solution for mobile users too. I have an index.php for the main site, and an index2.php for mobile users.

.htaccess files are Chinese for me, can you give me some help? I'd need the following to happen:

1. Desktop users get what index.php gives them and the URL bar shows mydomain.co
2. Mobile users get what index2.php gives them and the URL bar still shows mydomain.co

I had the following code and I even renamed index2.php to index.php and put it inside /mobile, but it somehow does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera|mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Don't use `[R=301]` while testing. It is a perment redirect, which is 'remembered' by the browser. If you want the user to see `http://domain.com`, you'll need to use an internal rewrite (without the `R` flag). The 2nd argument of the 2nd line is a regex, and therefore you should write it without the quotes.

Comment: Not using [R=301] means that I should keep [L] or remove [R=301,L] in its entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detecting whether http request coming from mobile or not. For that you can check also by following way and do as per requirements.

Try like this way:

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
header ("Location: http://www.domain.nl/mobiel?m");
}
else
{
      //for desktop do something 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should've guessed that! The only thing that I would add that if you need this to work on the iPad too, you might want to add "|ad" near iphone and ipod, so that it becomes ip(hone|od|ad).